# TableViewCell should not get reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `UITableview` in my project, and also i have `UITableviewcell` for that `UITableview`. The problem is that cells are getting reused.if it get reused, when i select button i want the image to be changed for single cell and button `isSelected =YES`. So the button's selected image is getting reuse for every cell.

So,kindly help me out with this problem .

Comment: When you dequeue a cell you have to assume it may be getting reused. This means you have to fully initialize all properties of the cell dequeued. If you do not initialize everything you will see remnants of what it was last used for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to see the cell which you have selected, and set a flag value as the selected index. and reload the table.

when you reload the table check the flag value and set the image which you want to set for the cell which is selected. it will give you different cell selection.

for example

```
int selectionFlag = -888;

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    if(selectionFlag == indexPath.row)
    {
        //set the image you want to set for the cell which is selected.
    }   
    else  
    {
        //the normal image you want to set.
    }  
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{   
    selectionFlag = indexPath.row;
    [tableView realoadData];  
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to set flag value because in my application, i am cells as attendance purpose. so that i the image changes once we select button. when button is selected the image we get is present image for selected ==YES.  and once again if we press button, so the image is absent image.like that it is dynamically operated.

Comment: so what your saying is like it will  have a image which is ticked and the other is going to be not ticked marked. the tick mark means that it is present and the non tick mark means not present. so i asume that the default view or image is going to be a simple squirt image which don't have a tick mark on it, and when you select the cell it is going to a cell with tick mark on it. is it that you want.

Comment: When i run it shows absent image and when i click on button it should show present image and i am having total 305 cells lets assume . so when i click the button for 4 and 5 th cell the cell is reusing the 4 th and 5th cell and it is showing the present image for alternate cells also .. so, i should avoid that problem.

Comment: added a new answer. If  you have any doubts pleas free to add comments on it, i will get back to you as soon i see it. hop it will help  you. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In indexPathRow before return 
cell button.tag=indexPath.row;

In buttonclick action

//
-(IBAction)BtnAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *buttonIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag];
    //Type cast it to CustomCell
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:buttonIP];
    if(button.isSelected==NO)
    {
        cell.Imageview.image=selectedImage;
        button.isSelected=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.Imageview.image=OldImage;
        button.isSelected=NO;
    }

    [table reloaddata];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of using the above code you can use this line of code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath        
{  
    if(firstTime)  
    {  
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected image"];  
        [attatancearry addObject:value];  
    }  
    if(secondTime)  
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"absent image"];  
        [attatancearry removeObject:value];    
    }
}
```

and add the value to an another nsmutablearry as the attendence is added and when you press the same cell again you have to remove the value from the nsmutablearray you have added before, and reset the image back to absent. but you don't have to reload the entire tableview it will just change the cell which you have select right now. as your adding the value or index number of the cell into a array you can use the selection value for further use.